# HTML table body shows behind theader on scroll

Tags: html, css, html-table, css-position

I have a table and it is currently using `border-collapse: separate` property. My header is completely fine and the borders are looking great.

[image]

The problem is when I scroll, the borders start looking weird, as in the below image:

[image]

I realize that this is related to the way I have setted the `border-collapse` property, but is there a way I can have some sort of background on the `thead` or `tr`? Any workaround on this?

In the below snippet, as everyone can see, the borders on the header are "disappearing", I wanted to somehow add some sort of a background behind the `thead` so the borders could be kept the same as if there was no scroll.

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
```

```html
<style>
  table {
    font-family: arial, sans-serif;
    border-collapse: separate;
    width: 100%;
  }
  
  .first-col {
    position: sticky;
    left: 1px;
  }
  
  th {
    background-color: #d1d1d1;
  }
  
  thead {
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    z-index: 99999;
  }
  
  td,
  th {
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    text-align: left;
    padding: 8px;
  }
</style>

<div style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"> Row1 of Header </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"> Row2 of Header </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"> Row3 of Header </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Row1 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row2 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row3 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row4 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row5 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row6 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row7 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row8 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row9 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row10 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Consider adding part of your code so it can be researched by others. Also from the images and your description it is really unclear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: It is possible that you are witnessing a problem when the system tries to map CSS pixels to screen pixels (1 CSS pixel has several screen pixels on some modern devices and the edge effect when one is mapped to the other can lead to some screen pixels getting 'left behind' so making lines look fatter/slimmer. Please add code so that we can investigate further: See https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example

Comment: @JiříMelen I updated my answer with the example.

Comment: @AHaworth I added an example.

Comment: All I can see is that as I scroll is that bits of the table body appear under those gaps (and sometimes the bit is a line, making the gap seem smaller). Is that what you see or is there something else?

Comment: @AHaworth Yes that's basically it, I'd like to know if there's a way to somehow add a white background behind? (main solution that came into my mind, but of course I'll take any solution to this). I just don't want to display the body behind the theader.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suppose you mean that the contents and borders of the scrolled cells appear between the header cells when the table is scrolled up.

To avoid that, you can add an `:after` pseudo element to `thead` with a white `background-color`, `z-index: -1` and other settings as shown below. Note that I extended the selector in the CSS rule for the `position:sticky` elements in the header (`.first-col`) to include *all* `th` cells

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

table {
  font-family: arial, sans-serif;
  border-collapse: separate;
  width: 100%;
}

.first-col, .first-col ~ th {
  position: sticky;
  left: 1px;
}

td,
th {
  border: 1px solid #dddddd;
  text-align: left;
  padding: 8px;
}
th {
  background-color: #d1d1d1;
}

thead {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0;
  z-index: 99999;
}


thead::after {
  content: '';
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  z-index: -1;
}
```

```html
<div style="max-height: 300px; overflow: auto;">
  <table>
    <thead>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"> Row1 of Header </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"> Row2 of Header </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <th class="first-col"> Row3 of Header </th>
        <th> 1 </th>
        <th> 2 </th>
        <th> 3 </th>
      </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>
      <tr>
        <td> Row1 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row2 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row3 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row4 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row5 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row6 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row7 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row8 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row9 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td> Row10 of Body </td>
        <td> 11 </td>
        <td> 24 </td>
        <td> 32 </td>
      </tr>
    </tbody>
  </table>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you! This was the answer I was looking for!